# The problem that the position of the figure drawn in the android compose canvas cannot be changed in real time

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I would like to ask a question because there is a blockage while working on an android project.

```kotlin
compose compiler version 1.3.2

Kotlin version 1.7.20

android BOM 2023.01.00
```

I am currently using android compose and drawing shapes using canvas.

If you change the state offset value of a shape using detectDragGestures inside the Composable function, the shape is drawn in real time. If you change the value by declaring it as a mutableStateOf variable after declaring it using an external function or class, it will not be drawn again. Is there something I'm missing?

The way I solved it by myself was to delete and re-draw every time within the detectDragGestures scope. I think that this method is not good, so I leave a question.

Sorry for the stupid question from a novice developer. Thank you for the advice for a better direction and growth!

(Handling nullable too!! Sorry for the expression. I could do a little better, but I'm focusing on the redraw part, so I'll finish it once I've solved this part.)

**screen**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun screen() {

    val shapeList = remember { mutableStateListOf<IShape>() }
    var selectShape = remember {
        mutableStateOf<IShape?>(null)
    }
    
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(onClick = {
            shapeList.add(
                Circle(
                    shapeList.size + 1,
                    Rect(Offset(200f, 200f), Offset(200f, 200f)),
                    100f
                )
            )
        }) {
            Text(text = "button")
        }

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                  detectTapGestures {
                      val shape = shapeList.firstOrNull { iShape ->
                        when (iShape) {
                            is Circle -> iShape.rect
                                .getPivot()
                                .distanceTo(it) == iShape.radius

                            else -> {
                                // TODO
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    selectShape.value = shape
                 }
              }
           .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures(
                    onDragStart = {
                        Log.d("selectShape", selectShape.value.toString())
                    },
                    onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        if (selectShape.value != null) {
                            selectShape.value!!.drag(dragAmount)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }, onDraw = {
            for (item in shapeList)
                item.draw(this)
        }
        )
     }
   }
}
```

**IShape**

```kotlin
interface IShape{
    fun draw(scope : DrawScope)
    fun isDrawable() : Boolean
    fun drag(dragRate : Offset)
    fun scale(scaleTo : Float)
    fun select(select : Offset)
}
```

**Shape**

```kotlin
sealed class Shape :IShape{
    abstract val id: Int
    abstract var rect : Rect
    override fun isDrawable(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun drag(dragRate: Offset) {
        rect.position = dragRate
        Log.d("drag change",rect.position.toString())
    }

    override fun scale(scaleTo: Float) {

    }

    override fun select(select: Offset) {

    }

}

data class Circle(
    override val id:Int,
    override var rect : Rect,
    var radius : Float
):Shape(){
    override fun draw(scope: DrawScope) {
        scope.drawCircle(center = rect.position,
            radius = radius,
            color = Color.Black)
    }


}
```

```kotlin
fun Offset.distanceTo(target: Offset): Float {
    return sqrt((this.x - target.x).pow(2) + (this.y - target.y).pow(2))
}
```

Comment: I'd take a guess at: override the equals method in your `Shape` sealed class. You also don't need the interface and the sealed class, either use an interface or a sealed class to simplify the problem